# \+ not working as expected in sed on os x

Tags: regex, sed

It seems like you use + to replace strings of 'at least one' of a certain character https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/how-to-strip-multipe-spaces-to-one-using-sed

However I'm having trouble getting this to work as expected on OS X 10.9.3.

I am trying to replace all strings of one or more n -- in many programming languages it would be: `n{1,}` -- with a single n.

But when I try to do this with sed it is not working

```
$ echo 'nnnn nnnn 234 nnnnnn nnnnnn nnnnnnnn nnnn 2340 492 nnnn nnnn 324 nnnnn 302' | sed 's/n/2/g'
2222 2222 234 222222 222222 22222222 2222 2340 492 2222 2222 324 22222 302

$ echo 'nnnn nnnn 234 nnnnnn nnnnnn nnnnnnnn nnnn 2340 492 nnnn nnnn 324 nnnnn 302' | sed 's/n+/2/g' ## this is what I want to do but it is not working


$ echo 'nnnn nnnn 234 nnnnnn nnnnnn nnnnnnnn nnnn 2340 492 nnnn nnnn 324 nnnnn 302' | sed 's/n*/n/g' ##replaces the empty string, which I don't want
n n n2n3n4n n n n n n2n3n4n0n n4n9n2n n n n3n2n4n n n3n0n2n
```

Comment: `sed 's/n\+/2/g'` is that `+` supposed to be escaped? Did you mean `sed 's/n+/2/g'`

Comment: @John3136: `sed` uses _basic_ regexes by default, where `+` is an _ordinary_ character; to make it _special_, it must be _escaped_ (but that only works on _some_ platforms, because `\+` is not part of the POSIX standard for basic regexes, and, indeed, it doesn't work on OSX, which is the crux of the problem here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"+" is not supported by default, you should use `-E` flag to use extended expressions syntax:

command will look like:
`sed -E 's/n+/2/g'`

Answer (score 4):

### tl;dr:

Use **`\{1,\}`** instead of `\+` to make it work on OSX and, more generally, to write **portable basic regexes**:

```
echo 'n nn nnn' | sed 's/n\{1,\}/2/g' # -> '2 2 2'
```

If portability is not a concern, use `-E` to enable support for *extended* regexes, which do support (unescaped) `+`:

```
echo 'n nn nnn' | sed -E 's/n+/2/g'  # -> '2 2 2'
```

---

Duplication symbol `\+` is NOT part of [the POSIX definition of a *basic* regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), which is what `sed` uses:

- *exclusively*, according to the POSIX spec.
- *by default*, in implementations that provide *optional* support for *extended* regexes (such as GNU `sed` with `-r` (and also `-E`) and FreeBSD/OSX `sed` with `-E`).

*Some* `sed` implementations (e.g., GNU `sed`) *do* support `\+` in basic regexes nonetheless.
*Others* (e.g., FreeBSD/OSX `sed`) do *not*.

Thus, to **write truly portable and POSIX-compliant `sed` scripts**:

- do NOT use *extended* regexes
- use `\{1,\}` instead of `\+`

**Caveat**

As GNU `sed`'s support for `\+` demonstrates, **various `sed` implementations support non-standard *extensions* to the POSIX standard even in *basic* regexes**.

**Therefore, getting a particular *basic*-regex `sed` script to work on one platform is NOT a guarantee that the script will work on all POSIX platforms.**

And **even if multiple platforms support a given extension *in principle*, the *syntax may differ*.**

Case in point: both GNU `sed` and FreeBSD/OSX `sed` support *word-boundary assertions* in basic regexes (and extended ones, too), but the *syntax differs and is mutually exclusive*:

- GNU `sed`: `\<` / `\>` or `\b`
- FreeBSD/OSX `sed`: `[[:<:]]` / `[[:>:]]`

Answer (score 2):

Your sed may not support `\+`, in which case you can simply repeat the character twice:

```
sed 's/nn*/2/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

GNU sed supports [extended regular expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-regexps) if you give it the `-r` flag.

```
sed -r 's/n+/2/g'
```

Comment: `-r` is for _GNU_ `sed`; the OP is on OSX (FreeBSD `sed`), where you need `-E`.